# Why is Scan Rate Measured in Hz, not Hz/s?

Tags: units, spectroscopy

Spectrometers have a specification called *scan rate*. As spectrometers measure spectrum, one would think the units of scan rate would be like Hz/s - meaning, the bandwidth scanned per unit time. Like if a spectrometer scanned 10 GHz in 100 ms, the scan rate would be $$\frac{10 \textrm{ GHz}}{100 \textrm{ ms}}= 100 \textrm{ GHz/s}$$

However, it seems as though scan rate is measured in Hz. For example, [this commercial spectrometer](https://www.thorlabs.com/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=4713) has a 5 THz spectral range with a scan rate "up to 20 Hz". What does this mean exactly?

Another example is [this paper](https://www.osapublishing.org/DirectPDFAccess/46775DA5-9687-E23A-2B041334A75EE2D3_86927/oe-14-1-430.pdf?da=1&id=86927&seq=0&mobile=no) where they say right in the abstract "At a scan rate of 9 kHz a time resolution of
230 fs is accomplished"

Comment: The scan rate is a measure of how long the spectrometer takes to scan a mass spectrum so “up to 20 Hz” means that the quickest a mass spectrum can be scanned is one-twentieth of a second.

Comment: @Farcher Ah - so it scans 5 THz in 0.05 s, a rate of 100 THz/s ? Is that right?

Comment: Personally I would denote the units of a regular bandwidth-per-unit-time as $\mathrm{Hz}^2$ rather than $\mathrm{Hz/s}$. But I'm not sure what use such a measure would have unless your spectrometer had an adjustable bandwidth that it scanned.

Comment: Sometimes, it's better not to combine units arithmetically if they make sense in the uncombined form. Thus in countries which use the metric system vehicle engine fuel efficiency is expressed in litres per 100 km. You don't divide the volume by the distance to obtain an area. OTOH, it can be humorous in certain circles to express fuel efficiency in picohectares. :)

Answer (score 2):

Based on comments by @dmckee and @Farcher , it seems like the unstated assumption is that spectrometers always scan their entire available bandwidth.

So for the [commercial spectrometer](https://www.thorlabs.com/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=4713) in the question with a 5 THz spectral range with a scan rate "up to 20 Hz", the scan rate is:

$$(5 \textrm{ THz})(20 \textrm{ Hz})=\frac{5 \textrm{ THz}}{0.05 \textrm{ s}}=100 \textrm{ THz/s}$$

One of the comments suggested using Hz$^2$ as a unit; seems sort of awkard; this would then be 100 THzHz, or 100 x 10$^{12}$ Hz$^2$ or even 100 MHz$^2$.

On a further note, another [commercially available spectrometer](https://ekspla.com/product/t-spec-series-real-time-terahertz-spectrometer/) calls it "Real-time data acquisition" instead of scan rate, with "10 spectra/s" meaning the entire bandwidth is scaned in 0.1 s.

Comment: I think that pretty much everything until the 'further note' is irrelevant and incorrect. It scans a certain number of frequencies in a given time period, so you'll just end up with Hz.

Answer (score 2):

The bandwidth of the spectrum is a red herring. Scan Rate refers to how fast the spectrum analyzer can generate a spectrum - ie the number of spectra per second. The limiting factor in this measurement is the discrete **number of data points** in the spectrum, not the continuous frequency bandwidth of the spectrum.

So a scan rate of 20Hz means (for example) that the analyser can refresh the screen 20 times per second. This is useful if you are looking at changes in the spectrum on the time scale of 1s or more.

Saying that a bandwidth of 10GHz has been scanned in 100ms is meaningless for comparison purposes unless you also know the **resolution** of the scan. A spectrum analyser which can acquire 1000 data points from a spectrum which is a mere 1kHz wide in 0.1s is more powerful than one which takes the same time to acquire 100 data points from a spectrum 1THz wide.

Number of spectra is dimensionless so the unit of $Hz$ is correct.

Comment: Can you please define resolution in this context? Surly this isn't *resolution bandwidth*. Perhaps it is similar to digital resolution?

Comment: @axsvl77 By *resolution* I mean how far apart in kHz or GHz etc are the data points in the spectrum.

Comment: Does your answer apply to [swept-tuned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum_analyzer#Swept-tuned) spectrum analysis? Seems like you are assuming digitization is the only way to go.

Comment: Yes my answer applies to swept-tuned also, but the connection is not so obvious. The wiki gives scan time $ST=k(Span)/RBW^2$. It is not clear if the numerator has units of Hz, but that needs to be if ST has units of s. Scan rate SR=1/ST so SR has units of Hz.